# Recebo muitos email com "i.e." no corpo do texto. Em que contexto se utiliza? Parece-me muito informal , de usar só em emails?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, tradução, estrangeirismos, definição

Recebo muitos emails com “i.e.” no corpo do texto. Em que contexto se utiliza? Apenas numa situação menos formal?
Por exemplo email

Diferente de *idem
id est* = isto é?

Comment: id est , em Latim o que significa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como podemos ver no dicionário priberam i.e. é só uma abreviatura de «isto é» e pode usar-se em qualquer contexto.

> i.e. (redução do latim id est, isto é) abreviatura
>
> Expressão usada para iniciar uma explicação adicional em relação a
>   algo que foi dito anteriormente. = ISTO É
>   Palavras relacionadas: id
>   est .
>
> "i.e.", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, https://dicionario.priberam.org/i.e. [consultado em
>   02-12-2019].

Answer (score 8):

Discordando da resposta de @Jorge B, eu não vejo "i.e." como uma abreviatura a ser usada **em situações informais**. Embora sirva como abreviatura para "isto é", na verdade é uma expressão em Latim que representa **"id est"**.  Em português a abreviatura de "id est" coincide com a abreviatura da tradução, "isto é". No entanto, a abreviatura é usada em outras línguas, e em Inglês talvez até mais frequentemente do que em português. Nesse caso, "id est" seria traduzida por "that is", e fica claro que "i.e." não é uma abreviatura de "isto é".

Sendo uma abreviatura cujo significado é desconhecido pela maioria da população brasileira, seu uso em situações informais como emails, cartas para amigos, bilhetes, recados, etc, mesmo que reconhecida pelo destinatário, **é pedante** quando se pode perfeitamente escrever "isto é", "ou seja", "quero dizer", digo, etc. "Id est", a meu ver, tem o mesmo grau de formalidade que "ad hoc" ou "ad lib" e o uso da abreviatura não seria menos formal.

Comment: Quando eu tiver tempo eu vou fazer uma pesquisa mais profunda para verificar se i.e. tem uso informal ou não. A minha ideia é que se usa de forma informal em Portugal. Também pode ser diferença transatlântica. E a votação pode indicar isso mesmo.

Comment: Pessoas que estão acostumadas a ler textos técnicos podem acabar se habituando à expressão e usando informalmente também.

Comment: @stafusa  Pode acontecer, mas não deve ser o que ocorre habitualmente.  Devido à minha profissão eu leio muitos textos técnicos diariamente, tanto em Inglês quanto em português, e encontro "i.e." com frequência.  Mas não uso a expressão quando escrevo textos informais como cartas e emails.  Quem conhece a expressão, iria achar pedantismo.  Quem não conhece, não iria entender.  Nunca é demais lembrar que "i.e" não é uma abreviatura de "isto é", e sim de "id est", que vem a ser traduzido por "isto é".

Comment: @Centaurus eu uso muito frequentemente em textos informais (emails, mensagens de texto) *em inglês*, num contexto de negócios. "i.e." e "e.g." são em grande parte desconhecidas pela população. "e.g." simplesmente não é usada fora de contextos acadêmicos, a forma preferida é "p. ex."

Comment: Aquele que deu o downvote deveria dizer o motivo, de modo que eu pudesse aprimorar a resposta.

Comment: o que significa  e,g, referido no comentário em cima?